# Js класс, передача переменной из ajax

Tags: javascript, ооп

```
function api() {        
    _self = $(this);

    setData('parameters', {
        host: $("#host").val(),
        aid: $("#aid").val(),
        uid: 876,
        token: $("#token").val()
    });

    function getAid() {         
        query ='uid='+getData('parameters').uid;
        $.ajax({
            url: getData('parameters').host+'ajax/album.php',
            type: "GET",
            data: query,
            success: function(response){            
                getData('parameters').aid = 123;
                console.log(getData('parameters').aid); //123   
            }       
        });             
    }

    getAid();

    function setData(key, data) {
        _self.data(key, data);
    }

    function getData(key) {
        return _self.data(key);
    }
    console.log(getData('parameters').aid); //876
}
```

вот учусь писать код, используя классы на js
подскажите пожалуйста, как мне в success измененить переменную, что бы распространялось изменение на весь класс, а не только внути функции success.

Там в комментах я пояснил, думаю вы поняли меня.

Comment: строго говоря на js нет классов.

Comment: кстати а зачем у вас там вообще $(this) ? просто чтобы data хранить ?

Answer (score 1):

ООП в данном случае не при чем. Функция [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) по-умолчанию выполняется асинхронно. Это значит, что последний вывод `console.log(getData('parameters').aid);` выведет значение **до того, как оно будет изменено**. Чтобы этого избежать, можно выставить параметр `async: false`. Или, что лучше, воспользоваться событийной моделью - когда функции, работающие асинхронно вызывают соответствующее событие при завершении, на что в свою очередь вешается обработчик.

Comment: в этом случае async: false меня спасет, но мне еще нужно передавать jsonp данные, там это работать небудет, как быть?
можно подробей про ваш второй предложенный вариант?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) и [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/). Логика проста: по завершению выполнения асинхронной функции она вызывает некое событие, которое потом можно отловить с помощью функции-обработчика.

Answer (score 1):

Для понимания того, как создавать классы в Javascript, посмотрите статью:
http://ru.wh-db.com/article/javascript-classes-in-javascript/

Там очень простой пример, сравнивают как создать класс на языке Java и такой же класс на языке Javascript.

По поводу Ajax, вот неплохая статья:
http://ru.wh-db.com/article/kak-otpravit-formu-bez-perezagruzki-stranici/